# Sublime Text on Mac error

Tags: macos, text, editor

I downloaded sublime text for mac. Everything is okay but it have a problem. I try other editor like TextMate, and Textmate is ok.
You can see it in the picture.

I tried to set all setting but

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgPlb.png

Despite i change the focus to line 4, but when i type something, it still add to line 6 ? So, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Sublime Text 3 instead. You can get it here: http://www.sublimetext.com/3 .